# AoCG2021 Day 12: Oct's Fool

Tags: code-golf, decision-problem, grid

Part of [**Advent of Code Golf 2021**](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/24068/78410) event. See the linked meta post for details.

The story continues from [AoC2017 Day 11](https://adventofcode.com/2017/day/11).

[Obligatory why me and not Bubbler link](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/59839491#59839491)

---

After having rescued a child process lost on a hexagonal infinite grid, you hear someone else screaming for help. You turn around, and unsurprisingly, there is another program looking for its *own* child process. "Help! It's gotten lost in an infinite octagonal grid!"

Well, it's not *all* octagonal, obviously. Instead, it's actually a [4-8-8 tiling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truncated_square_tiling):

[image]

An octagonal tile (X) has eight neighbors, indicated by eight directions (N, NE, E, SE, S, SW, W, NW). A square tile (Y) has only four neighbors in cardinal directions (N, E, S, W).

The program gives you the path taken by the child process. The initial tile is an octagon. You try following the directions one by one, and ... something's wrong in the middle. "Look, it can't move diagonally from a square tile, you see?"

Given a sequence of movements, determine if it is valid on the 4-8-8 grid, assuming the initial position of an octagon.

**Input:** A list of strings entirely consisting of `N`, `NE`, `E`, `SE`, `S`, `SW`, `W`, `NW`. Or a single string containing these strings with a single delimiter (space, comma, newline, or any other char that is not one of `NESW`) in between. (If the input is `["N", "E", "NW", "NE", "E", "SE"]` then you can take it as e.g. `"N,E,NW,NE,E,SE"`)

**Output:** A value indicating whether it is valid or not. You can choose to

- output truthy/falsy using your language's convention (swapping is allowed), or
- use two distinct, fixed values to represent true (affirmative) or false (negative) respectively.

Standard [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) rules apply. The shortest code in bytes wins.

### Test cases

Truthy:

```
[]
["S"]
["SW"]
["N", "E", "NW", "NE"]
["NE", "SE", "SW", "NW", "N", "E", "S", "W"]
```

Falsy:

```
["N", "E", "NW", "NE", "E", "SE"]
["NE", "SE", "N", "E", "S", "SW", "NW", "W"]
["N", "NW"]
```

Comment: Can we take it as, say, `xx x xx xx x x xx xx x` or something?

Comment: @emanresuA > Or a single string containing these strings with a single delimiter (space, comma, newline, or any other char that is not one of NESW) in between

Comment: I meant, can we take it without distinquishing between NESW and replacing them all with  a single character?

Comment: @emanresuA I'mma say no to that, because that doesn't seem in the spirit of Bubbler's original challenge.

Comment: Would something like `, ` be allowed as delimiter? It is not a single character but arguably a single delimiter.

Answer (score 8):

## Regex (any), 27 bytes

```regex
^((.\n.\n)*..\n?)*(.\n)*.?$
```

Matches valid strings, taking input as a newline-separated string. There's probably a way to golf this regex. This version thanks to @AnttiP.

## Javascript, 34 bytes

```js
/^((.\n.\n)*..\n?)*(.\n)*.?$/.test
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNHNy09J/Z@cn1ecn5Oql5OfrvFfP05DQyMmOCZYQVMLRFQb1WpqIQmAWPp6JanFJf81lPxcFYJdFfwUgJRCcLiCX7hCuJKm5n8A)

```
^                          From the start...
 (             )*          Match 0+ times...
  (      )*                Match 0+ times...
   .\n.\n                  A pair of 1-char strings
           ..\n?           Followed by a 2-char string with possible separator (in case this is the end)
 (             )*          This block will match 2-char strings until the end as long as the 1-char strings are paired
                 (.\n)*    Match any amount of . after this
                       .?$ Match possible trailing . at the end
```

This relies on the fact that length 1 strings modify the parity of whether we're on an octagon or square, and whether diagonal (length-2 strings) are valid.

### Old version, 35 bytes

```
^(((\S\S )*\S ){2})*(\S\S )*\S \S\S
```

Matches invalid strings, taking input space-separated.

```
^                                   From the start...
 ((           ){2})*                Match an even number of times...
   (\S\S )*                         Possibly any amount of length-2 strings                      
           \S                       Followed by a length-1 string
                    (\S\S )*        Possibly match any amount of length-2 strings
                            \S \S\S Match a length-1 string followed by a length-2 string.
```

Comment: A shorter regex is `^((.\n.\n)*..\n?)*(.\n)*.?$`. This matches valid strings. Using newlines as separators saves 2 bytes, for a total of -8 bytes.

Comment: It amazes me how much everyone is still struggling to golf their regexes down...

Answer (score 8):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <strike>45</strike>, <strike>44</strike>, 36 bytes (@Jonathan Allan)

```python
lambda a:`a.title()`[1::2]>`a`[1::2]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/qfZhvzPycxNyklUSHRKiFRrySzJCdVQzMh2tDKyijWLiERyvqfll@kUJJaXKKQmacQw6UABRrRsXC2TrRSsBIqNxyV76eko6DkCiL8wsGkK5o8WC4YQoYjqYPrCwYRhE2FK8djAZqhyPZhs8APWVDTCswsKMrMK9EAhYqOgrqunbqOQpqGUkyMkl5WfmYeWFxTU/M/AA)

##### Older versions

```python
lambda a:repr(a.title())[1::2]>repr(a)[1::2]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM7YoKPqfZhvzPycxNyklUSHRqii1oEgjUa8ksyQnVUNTM9rQysoo1g4iCuX9T8svUihJLS5RyMxTiOFSgAKN6Fg4WydaKVgJlRuOyvdT0lFQcgURfuFg0hVNHiwXDCHDkdTB9QWDCMKmwpXjsQDNUGT7sFnghyyoaQVmFhRl5pVogEJFR0Fd105dRyFNQykmRkkvKz8zDyyuqan5HwA)

```python
lambda a:(A:=repr(a.title())[1::2])>A.upper()
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hVCxCsIwEN39iiNLcxAL6iKBFjp07dKhQ9MhYoqVmoYYB78@0iilLaI3PO7de3cPzjzdZdCHo7G@TYTv5e10liA5zXhilbFUxq5zvaKI9Y7zfYNpFj@MUZaibwcLTt0ddBrEBj5F62bqWU1KsqTVkheEAclHKKqA@UoPWvnGauab9soR/l@d7D8CVkfned8CivkQeWiN7bSj41cYRNs0YtBSIgSJr0OnwxwR/Qs)

##### Explanation (all versions)

This expects a backslash- (or tab- or newline-) separated string and returns True for invalid and False for valid paths.

It works by detecting odd-length stretches of single-character commands followed by at least one double-character command.

The idea is essentially: if we had `X` for principal directions and `XY` for the others we could just concatenate take every other character and check for `Y`s.

Almost as good is to `title`-case the input string which puts a capital instead of `X` and a small instead of `Y`.

Now, I found no cheap way of getting rid of the delimiter, but almost as good we use backslash or tab or newline and apply `repr`. This replaces each separator with its two-character escaped representation such that they do not interfere with parity.

It remains to check <strike>for any lowercase letters which we do by comparing with `upper`</strike> whether any differences with the non title cased inputs have survived the skipping step.

Comment: In Python 2 you can use backticks in place of `repr` calls, so ``lambda a:`a.title()`[1::2]>`a`[1::2]`` saves eight.

Answer (score 7):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), <s>46</s> <s>43</s> 42 bytes

*Edit: -1 byte thanks to pajonk*

```r
function(s)any(cumsum(x<-nchar(s))%%2&x>1)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/qfl19SlpiTmWL7P600L7kkMz9Po1gzMa9SI7k0t7g0V6PCRjcvOSOxCCiqqapqpFZhZ6gJ16SRrKGpyYXEUwpWQhcIRxfxU9JRUHIFEX7hYNIVQwVYNhhChiOphOsMBhHEmAzXgNcSNIOR7cRuiV84Fn/CDAJL/gcA)

Function `notvalid`: outputs `TRUE` if the path is not valid, `FALSE` if it's a valid path.

**How?**
If the path is valid, then 2-character moves (that can only be from an octagon) always move to an octagon; 1-character moves flip between octagons & squares.  So, we're in a square if we've had an odd number of 1-character moves.
Invalid moves are attempted 2-character moves from squares, so we need to check if any of these co-incide with positions after an odd number of 1-character moves.

`any(...)` = is this question TRUE value at any position:
`cumsum(x)%%2` = have we had an odd number of 1-character moves?
`&x>1` = and, if so, is x currently 2?

Comment: Won't `cumsum` instead of `diffinv` work for [-1 byte](https://tio.run/##K/qfl19SlpiTmWL7P600L7kkMz9Po1gzMa9SI7k0t7g0V6PCRjcvOSOxCCiqqapqpFZhZ6gJ16SRrKGpyYXEUwpWQhcIRxfxU9JRUHIFEX7hYNIVQwVYNhhChiOphOsMBhHEmAzXgNcSNIOR7cRuiV84Fn/CDAJL/gcA "R – Try It Online")?

Answer (score 6):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 6 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
ẈÄPƝḂẸ
```

A mondadic Link that accepts a list of lists of characters and yields `0` if valid or `1` if invalid.

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///hro7DLQHH5j7c0fRw147/h9sfNa35/z86OpZLJ1opWAlChUNoPyUdBSVXEOEXDiZdoeJgsWAIGY4kD1cfDCJwmwJXhsVANEOQzUc20A/EiQUA)**

#### How?

The only way to reach a square is via a sequence of an odd number of cardinal directions, after which if a diagonal direction is given the input is invalid. The cardinal directions are length one, while diagonal ones are length two. Thus if the cumulative sum of lengths of the input contains two odd numbers in a row it is an invalid instruction.

```
ẈÄPƝḂẸ - Link: instuctions
Ẉ      - length of each instruction
 Ä     - cumulative sums -> odd when taken to a square given a valid prefix
   Ɲ   - for neighbours:
  P    -   product (only odd * odd is odd)
    Ḃ  - is odd? (vectorises)
     Ẹ - any?
```

Answer (score 5):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), <s>33 32</s> 29 bytes

```ruby
->l{l.all?{|y|y[1]?l:[l=!l]}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvyfZvtf1y6nOkcvMSfHvrqmsqYy2jDWPscqOsdWMSe2tvZ/gUJatJKSXnFBTmaJhr2OZiwXWCQYi1A4ppifjquOX7iOnysWKVedYCAKB8sDlQXroOrnUlYIz1fILC5RyE3NzEtVyE3MTUQzFKQLp8kQMyHmY3WZH4rofwA)

Look ma, no regex!

#### How?

Reuse l as a flag that is initialized with a truthy value, and translates as true->octagon, false->square.
The sequence is invalid if we have to move diagonally (y[1] is true when y is 2 characters long) from a square (l is false). If y is only 1 character, we are moving from an octagon to a square or viceversa, so we have to flip the flag. This is enclosed in an array to make the operation return a truthy value.

Answer (score 4):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 9 bytes

```
vL:‹$¦∷*a
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyIiLCIiLCJ2TDrigLkkwqbiiLcqYSIsIiIsIltcIk5FXCIsIFwiU0VcIiwgXCJTV1wiLCBcIk5XXCIsIFwiTlwiLCBcIkVcIiwgXCJTXCIsIFwiV1wiXSJd)

There's got to be a better way to do this. Outputs reversed - 1 for invalid, 0 for valid,

```
vL        # Lengths
     ¦∷   # Cumulative sums modulo 2, tracking when on a square and when not  
    $  *  # Multiplied by
  :‹      # Those same lengths decremented
          # Each one is only true when on a square *and* trying to move diagonally
          # Which is invalid    
        a # Are any true? If so, there's an invalid one somewhere.
```

Answer (score 4):

## [Retina 0.8.2](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language/a950ad7d925ec9316e3e2fb2cf5d49fd15d23e3d), 20 bytes

```
^(\w,?($|\w($|,)))*$
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otycxL/K@q4Z7wP04jplzHXkOlJqYcSOhoampqqfz/zxXMFRzO5afjquMXruPnyuXnqhMMROFgLlA0WAdJFsSHKYFIQhSClPiFAwA) Link includes test cases. Explanation: The regular expression only matches valid movements, i.e. those that only contain paired or trailing orthogonal directions. 18 bytes if newlines are allowed as separators:

```
^(.¶?($|.($|¶)))*$
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otycxL/K@qEZyg8z9OQ@/QNnsNlRo9ID60TVNTU0vl/3@uYK7gcC4/HVcdv3AdP1cuP1edYCAKB3OBosE6SLIgPkwJRBKiEKTELxwA) Link includes test suite that splits on comma for convenience.

Answer (score 4):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 15 bytes

```
⬤θ›³⁺﹪Ｌ⪫…θκω²Ｌι
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/z@gKDOvRMMxJ0ejUEfBvSg1sSS1SMNYRyEgp7RYwzc/pTQnX8MnNS@9JEPDKz8zT8O5Mjkn1TkjvwCkPltTR6FcE0gYATFUVaYmCFj//x8dreTnqqSjoBQMIcNBpB@EBBEQURARrhQb@1@3LAcA) Link is to verbose version of code. Outputs a Charcoal boolean i.e. `-` for valid, nothing for invalid. Explanation: An input is valid if the cumulative length modulo 2 plus the length of the current item never exceeds 2.

Answer (score 3):

## [Pari/GP](http://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr/), 32 bytes

```
a->t=0;[t=[1-t,t*x][#d]|d<-a];t'
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gsytRNL/ifpmD7P1HXrsTWwDq6xDbaULdEp0SrIjZaOSW2JsVGNzHWukT9f2JBQU6lRrGCrp1CQVFmXgmQqQTiKCmkaRRrauooREfHAgmlYCUIFQ6h/ZR0FJRcQYRfOJh0hYqDxYIhZDiSPFx9MIjAbQpcGRYD0QxBNh/ZQKBIbKzmfwA)

Here `t` is the state of the current tile: `0` means octagon, `1` means square.

When the direction has length 1, we just set `t` to `1-t`. If the length is 2, we multiply `t` by `x`, so `0` remains `0`, while `1` becomes a polynomial. If `t` is a polynomial, `1-t` and `t*x` are also polynomials. So invalid states are represented by polynomials.

Finally, we take the derivative of `t`. The derivative of a constant is `0`, which is falsy. The derivative of non-constant polynomials are truthy.

Answer (score 3):

## [Python](https://docs.python.org/3.8/),  <s>48</s>  47 bytes

```python
f=lambda a,o=1:o>1or a and f(a[1:],len(a[0])-o)
```

A recursive function that accepts a list of strings and returns an empty list (`[]`) if the input is valid or `True` if not.

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM7YoKPr/P802JzE3KSVRIVEn39bQKt/OML9IAcjLS1FI00iMNrSK1clJzQOyDGI1dfM1/6cBpUtSi0sUMvMUYrgUoEAjOhbO1olWClZC5Yaj8v2UdBSUXEGEXziYdEWTB8sFQ8hwJHVwfcEggrCpcOV4LEAzFNk@bBb4IQtqWoGZBUWZeSUaoFDRUVDXtVPXAQYdiKep@R8A)**

#### How?

`a` is our list of instructions.

`o` starts off as `1` (`,o=1`) and is a flag that indicates whether we are on an octagon (`1`) or square (`0`), this is updated for the next iteration by subtracting the current flag value from the current instruction length (`len(a[0])-o`).

If we try to go diagonally from a square then `o` becomes `2` (since \$2-0=2\$) and then the next iteration's evaluation of `o>1` causes a return value of `True`.

We drop the first (now executed) instruction from `a` (`a[1:]`) in order to perform the next iteration and if we find ourselves with an empty list the instructions were valid and `or a` causes this empty list to be returned.

Answer (score 3):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 55 bytes

```r
f=function(x,o=1)o>1||length(x)&&f(x[-1],nchar(x[1])-o)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/qfZgtEaaV5ySWZ@XkaFTr5toaa@XaGNTU5qXnpJRkaFZpqamkaFdG6hrE6eckZiUVAtmGspm6@5v80DRA/MbkktUjDQFOTC8jXUApWgrPC4Uw/JR0FJVcQ4RcOJl0RUmDhYAgZjqQEriUYROA1C64Su7FoRiHbgmasHxIf4Qqw6H8A)

Port of [@Jonathan Allan's recursive answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/238417/55372).

Outputs flipped `TRUE/FALSE`.

Answer (score 3):

## [Rust](https://www.rust-lang.org/), <strike>80</strike> 56 bytes

```rust
|p:&[&str]|p.iter().fold(0,|a,b|a+a%b.len()^b.len()&1)<2
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##lVE9T8MwEN3zKy6WsGzVpMDYFpi6dsmQIQrIBVuyZNxgOzA0@e0hdqOoRGoRN7yT796HpbON87008MGVIRSOCQylhQcJj9C39QqX2HlbtXWmvLCEZvKg38kdaznbt3zBb/aZFoP0Zez4nm4e@uCyTqKZPFggytSNZ8CN@xaWgjKAy7gNRb7EW1pWDLxtBGWzOcrR5VVxebdDDNA2wK6IuL3Cjbz8hMWZZvLIA/wvbZLGYMm1@yN5lnb@keKaxUibMarxmKFqq4zXJiXouHru4PYJQh90v@@yngTLJXDnhPXpNDq9X8VnSrAkOCrpTNolXf8D)

- -24 bytes by using fold and boolean operations (thanks @AnttiP)

Comment: A fold is shorter: `|p:&[&str]|p.iter().fold(0,|a,b|a+a%2%b.len()^b.len()&1)<2` -22 bytes

Comment: I looked into using fold but didn't consider using XOR, thanks!

Comment: Further -2 bytes: `|p:&[&str]|p.iter().fold(0,|a,b|a+a%b.len()^b.len()&1)<2` (the `%2` is redundant)

Answer (score 2):

## Python3, 82 bytes:

```
f=lambda x,s=0:((b:=len(x[0])==1)or s%2==0)and f(x[1:],s+b)if x else s%2==0 or s<2
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dYw9C4MwFEX/yltK8mgGtUuRvtHVxcFBMkQ0VEhjMA7216d@IVLa5Vy493Lce3z29nZ3QwiajHrVjYJJeIpSzuuUTGv5VEUSiWLsB/CXhChCZRvQ8xCnUvhrjZ2GCVrj2/0Ay/WRBDd0duSm8yN/Kce1gKqSM1jBtii3zJkAli3Iy5XZ3q9dsbE87ce/WPDfctx@CL8kZ/9ZODdSImL4AA)

Answer (score 2):

## [BQN](https://mlochbaum.github.io/BQN/), 13 bytes<sup>[SBCS](https://github.com/mlochbaum/BQN/blob/master/commentary/sbcs.bqn)</sup>

```
∨˝2|·×⟜»·+`≠¨
```

[Run online!](https://mlochbaum.github.io/BQN/try.html#code=RiDihpAg4oioy50yfMK3w5fin5zCu8K3K2DiiaDCqAoK4o2JKOKKouKJjcK3PkbCqCkg4p+o4p+o4p+pCuKLiCJTIgrii4giU1ciCiJOIuKAvyJFIuKAvyJOVyLigL8iTkUiCiJORSLigL8iU0Ui4oC/IlNXIuKAvyJOVyLigL8iTiLigL8iRSLigL8iUyLigL8iVyIKIk4i4oC/IkUi4oC/Ik5XIuKAvyJORSLigL8iRSLigL8iU0UiCiJORSLigL8iU0Ui4oC/Ik4i4oC/IkUi4oC/IlMi4oC/IlNXIuKAvyJOVyLigL8iVyIKIk4i4oC/Ik5XIuKfqQ==)

Exact port of [Jonathan Allan's Jelly answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/238414/64121). There are a few things that can be varied, e.g. [`` 1∊1‿1⍷·≠`2|≠¨ ``](https://mlochbaum.github.io/BQN/try.html#code=RiDihpAgMeKIijHigL8x4o23wrfiiaBgMnziiaDCqAoK4o2JKOKKouKJjcK3PkbCqCkg4p+o4p+o4p+pCuKLiCJTIgrii4giU1ciCiJOIuKAvyJFIuKAvyJOVyLigL8iTkUiCiJORSLigL8iU0Ui4oC/IlNXIuKAvyJOVyLigL8iTiLigL8iRSLigL8iUyLigL8iVyIKIk4i4oC/IkUi4oC/Ik5XIuKAvyJORSLigL8iRSLigL8iU0UiCiJORSLigL8iU0Ui4oC/Ik4i4oC/IkUi4oC/IlMi4oC/IlNXIuKAvyJOVyLigL8iVyIKIk4i4oC/Ik5XIuKfqQ==) works at the same length, but I couldn't find anything shorter.

Answer (score 2):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), <s>39</s> 34 bytes

```ruby
->i{/^((.,){2}*(.\w,)*)*.,.\w/!~i}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvyfZvtf1y6zWj9OQ0NPR7PaqFZLQy@mXEdTS1NLTwfI0lesy6z9X6CQFq2kFMsFpoPhjHAYy0/HVccvXMfPFS7gqhMMROFgUaBksA5IrbJCWmJOcSWaHpA0mkaIFoh2JEv8gOz//wE)

Method takes string with commas and returns true if the path is valid. The regexp looks for invalid path which is essentially an odd one-letter direction followed by a two-letter.

Thanks to ovs for very useful suggestions and -5 bytes!

Another less golfy but more interesting for me version doesn't work on TIO but takes arrays instead of strings and is 54 bytes:

```ruby
f=->t{c=0;t.chunk{_1[1]?1:2}.all?{2>c+=_1*c+_2.size%_1}}

p f[[]]
p f[["S"]]
p f[["SW"]]
p f[["N", "E", "NW", "NE"]]
p f[["NE", "SE", "SW", "NW", "N", "E", "S", "W"]]
# falsy
p f[["N", "E", "NW", "NE", "E", "SE"]]
p f[["NE", "SE", "N", "E", "S", "SW", "NW", "W"]]
p f[["N", "NW"]]
```

Comment: As there will be no consecutive commas in the input, some of the `\w` can be `.` instead. And you can actually swap to the order of arguments to `!~` saving another byte: https://tio.run/##KypNqvyfZvtf1y6zWj9OQ0NPR7PaqFZLQy@mXEdTS1NLTwfI0lesy6z9X6CQFq2kFMsFpoPhjHAYy0/HVccvXMfPFS7gqhMMROFgUaBksA5IrbJCWmJOcSWaHpA0mkaIFoh2JEv8gOz//wE

Answer (score 2):

**Turing Machine Code, <s>97</s> 77 bytes**

```
0 _ _ r halt
0 * * r 1
1 _ _ r 2
1 * * r 3
2 * * r 3
3 _ _ r 0
3 * * r halt-r
```

[Try it online](http://morphett.info/turing/turing.html?05ec4019351b477aa51076226bd57fae)

Takes space-separated input, thanks to AntiP for saving 20 bytes

Haven't tested on my Java implementation yet

Comment: -21 bytes by using spaces as separators: http://morphett.info/turing/turing.html?eb5b78bb36464aed05ade1e38593e7e7

Answer (score 2):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), 8 bytes

```
ṁ%2Ẋ*∫mL
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv6f@6ip8f/DnY2qRg93dWk96lid6/P////o6FidaKVgJTAZDqb8lHSUXIHYLxxEuELEQALBYCIcLgVVFwzE2HVC5dGNQNaIMA5hBJAbGwsA)

Approach based on [Jonathan Allan's Jelly answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/238414/95126).  Outputs zero (falsy) for valid paths, non-zero (truthy) for non-valid paths.

```
      mL  # get the lengths of the input strings
     ∫    # and calculate the cumulative sum
          # (so odd numbers indicate we're in a square)
   Ẋ*     # product of all adjacent pairs
          # (so odd numbers indicate a 2-character move
          # attempted from within a square)
ṁ%2       # map 'modulo 2' to all elements (gets odd numbers)
          # and output sum (non-zero if any elements were odd)
```

Answer (score 2):

## Thue, 84 bytes

```
@::=:::
S::=N
E::=N
W::=N
aN,::=b
aNN,::=a
bN,::=a
a,::=~1
b,::=~1
bNN::=~0
::=
a@,,
```

Takes comma-separated input

Comment: Rather than `X`, can you not map three of the cardinal directions to be the same as the fourth?

Comment: @Neil that is true, unfortunately while I was testing that I noticed that this version doesn't always work if the last direction is two letters so I need to fix that

Comment: Ok that should be fixed now

Answer (score 1):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 41 bytes

```
FreeQ[Or@@StringLength@#/. 1||1->3,1||2]&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78n6Zg@9@tKDU1MNq/yMEhuKQoMy/dJzUvvSTDQVlfT8GwpsZQ185YB0gbxar9DwBKl0QrK@jaKaRFK8fGKqgp6DtwVVfX6nApVCsFK0HpcCjDT0lHQckVRPiFg0lXmARYMBhChiMpgGsIBhF4zIGrw2YkmjHINqAYCRSqrf0PAA)

Answer (score 1):

## TypeScript Types, 107 bytes

```
type M<T,A=1,B=0,D="N"|"S"|"E"|"W">=T extends[infer C,...infer T]?C extends D?M<T,B,A>:A extends 1?M<T>:0:1
```

Finally, one that didn't benefit from `//@ts-ignore`!

[Try It Online!](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAsgPAFQDQEEC8BGJAhNAGJAETQCIA5EgHxIGUqSBRegdRID40EoIAPYCAHYATAM4BtAJYCAZhABOUAMJIAdGqmyFCALoB+Rdz6DRUQrvjJsqNgC4Uh-sJFQM5xLbw2MAKG+hIUAh4UGiwcGLabN4A9NFQ8QB6un7g0AgYIWFitCSRMXGJyf5pAEyZ8Nk0rHmx8VBJKQEIAMzl4eQkSFCMnd1krF3kTDUF9UWpgQAsbdlkTIM0891VveQDfatLOYPVUbWFvsVQAGLBoRUdg1v9q3Obq4u5e6MNR8cZ5+13C9f3Cw-rNarXb5OqvCbHMqfWa3EH7MbeIA)

### Ungolfed / Explanation

```
// DiagA: whether non-orthogonal moves are currently allowed
// DiagB: wtherer non-orthogonal moves are allowed in the other type of cell
type Main<Arr, DiagA = 1, DiagB = 0, OrthoDir = "N" | "S" | "E" | "W"> =
  // Check the first string in Arr
    Arr extends [infer Dir, ...infer Rest]
        ? Dir extends OrthoDir
      // If it's orthogonal, switch the type of cell
      ? Main<Rest, DiagB, DiagA>
      : DiagA extends 1
        // Otherwise, if diagonals are allowed, move into an octagonal cell (the default)
        ? Main<Rest>
        // Otherwise, return false
        : 0
    // The array is empty; return true
    : 1
```

Answer (score 1):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), 8 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
ηJ€gü*Éà
```

Input as a list of strings. Outputs `1` for invalid grids and `0` or an empty string `""` for valid grids (only `1` is truthy in 05AB1E, so this falls under the "*output truthy/falsy using your language's convention (swapping is allowed)*" rule).

Port of [*@JonathanAllan*'s Jelly answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/238414/52210).

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//3HavR01r0g/v0TrceXjB///RSn5KOkquQOwXDiJcobxgV6VYAA) or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/V9Waa@k8KhtkoKSfeX/c9u9HjWtST@8R@tw5@EF/3X@R0fH6kQrBSuByXAw5aeko@QKxH7hIMIVIgYSCAYT4XApqLpgIMauEyqPbgSyRoRxCCOA3NhYAA).

**Explanation:**

```python
η         # Get the prefixes of the (implicit) input-list
 J        # Join each inner prefix-list together to a single string
  €g      # Get the length of each string
    ü     # For each overlapping pair:
     *    #  Multiply them together
      É   # Check for each whether it's odd
       à  # And check if any were odd by leaving the maximum
          # (after which the result is output implicitly)
```

Empty or single-item inputs are `[]` after the `ü*`, which is why they result in an empty string `""`.